# Table cell wrapping (sometimes)

Tags: html, css, tablelayout

Have a got a table where the last cell in a row sometimes wraps but in other occasions displays correctly. Can't for the life of me see any difference between cases where it wraps and when it doesn't.

wrapping

http://bookgroupaustralia.obiweb.com.au/Book/guitar-chords

not wrapping

http://bookgroupaustralia.obiweb.com.au/Book/save

Comment: What table are we talking about?

Comment: On what OS/browser/version are you seeing problems? What cell, what table? I don't see any tabular data on those pages, so it would appear that you are [(ab)using tables for layout](http://phrogz.net/CSS/WhyTablesAreBadForLayout.html)?

Comment: You have [19 markup errors](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fbookgroupaustralia.obiweb.com.au%2FBook%2Fguitar-chords&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) in your HTML. Fixing that might fix some of the errors you are seeing. (I don't see them on Safari v5 on OS X.)

Comment: sorry, its the table (class="productTable") under "You may also be ..."

Comment: Am seeing the problem on Safari5 and FF3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `td.productItem` margin-right: 10px; to 5px;

Comment: That fixes it but puts the cells closer together that should be needed, and leaves a gap on the right.

Answer (score 3):

You appear to be setting `float: left;` on the `td` elements, which is apparently changing their display type and allowing them to wrap in some cases. Is there a reason for that? You may simply try removing it, from `/site/css/style.css`  (line 474)

```
.listing ul li.productItem, .listing ul li.productItemLast, td.productItem
{
float: left;
```

Comment: confirmed, removing the float attribute works (just checked with firebug).

Comment: Removing the float fixes the wrap but breaks other stuff. The float is there because the css handles displaying both lists and tables of titles. Would prefer to only use lists but the table is generated by a framework that we do not have control over.

Comment: The CSS can be refined so that the parts that should only apply to tables only apply to tables, and what should apply to lists only applies to lists.

Comment: The float left changes the display type to block which is what I want. Other elements like the Sale badge depend on it being inside a block. Cannot understand why some wrap and others don't

Comment: Then changing your margins and assuring your content does not overflow (or clipping it if it does) would be your solution.

Comment: Thats the weird thing I've checked the cell/row/table sizes and it should fitting fine. Plus I can find zero difference between the pages where it overflows and the ones where it does.